# Django: View didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

Basically I would like a user to input a number in a field and the fibonacci result to be printed but once the input is inserted into the input field I recieve that it returned None instead of an object

I have this code over here for my html form:

```
{% block content %}
  <form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" name="fcal" value="{{F}}" />
   <p>
    <input type="submit" name="fibo" value="Fibonacci" />
   </p>
  </form>
  {% if cal %}
     Your Fibonacci answer is {{cal}}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The content of my views.py is this one:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, render
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponseNotFound
import fibonacci


def fibocal(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
   fb = request.POST['fcal']
   cal = fibonacci.fibo(fb)
   return render(request, 'fibb/fibb.html', {'cal': cal})
else:
   return render(request, 'fibb/fibb.html', {})
```

And my fibonacci function is this one:

```
def fibo(n):
    if n == 0:
       return 0
    elif n == 1:
       return 1
    else:
        result = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)
        return result
```

I would like to know where the error is caused as I've looked again and again and I can see that I am returning a render not None

Full traceback include:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
158. % (callback.__module__, view_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /fibb/
Exception Value: The view fibb.views.fibb didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is not erroring out somewhere before the call to render? Could you edit your question and post the full traceback?

Comment: The error occurs only when I input a value in the input form and press the submit button

Comment: can you add your code for the fibb view..

Comment: And fix your indentation; the error is very likely to be there.

Comment: the error is at `fibb` view. But you are showing `fibo`. Show that view

Comment: On my end, the code errors out with a different exception - `request.POST['fcal']` is a string where as your Fibonacci function requires an integer. Converting the string into an int makes your code work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! The traceback helped me fix that as well!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *views.py* file, is there any *fibb* function that return a HTTPResponse? In the error trace, Django cannot find that response in *fibb* function in *fibb.views*. You can check the url directed to *fibb* function. Maybe it should be directed to *fibocal* function as you mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you such a silly mistake. I just had another function in there and just forgot to change it!